# Ubuntu 19.10. VLC player lag

Tags: nvidia, video, vlc, 19.10

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 version, and I noticed that VLC video player lags when playing videos. Videos seem like they are of lower frame rate and when skipping to a timestamp, both video and audio becomes choppy for a certain period of time.

Default Videos application seem to work fine though.

My configuration is:

- Ryzen 1700,
- 16 Gb RAM
- NVidia 1060 3Gb

so it should have no problems running HD videos in 2019.

- OS: Ubuntu 19.10.
- VLC version 3.0.8.
- NVidia drivers: tried 430,435 and 390, all the same.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Try disabling hardware acceleration in  vlc's menu > Tools >  Preferences > Input/Codecs > 1st option. Make sure to click Save after changing.

Comment: @doug Trided it, it seems to work a bit faster (when skipping video), but after skipping to a different frame, video and audio is still choppy for some time.